# Magento block division

Tags: layout, magento, block

How would I go about dividing the main content block into different areas?  I'm looking to create an area in the top left for a couple of images, then fill the rest of the block with text beside the image.

At the moment, using the wysiwyg editor I can add an image to the content, but I can't put text beside it, and that's a must for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Click the HTML button in the wysiwyg editor and manipulate the content the old-fashioned way. Perhaps wrap the images in a `<div style="float: left;">...</div>` element.